# Fetch data from a WFS endpoint and add it to a GeoPackage layer field automatically

Tags: qgis, wfs, geopackage

I have a GeoPackage layer with multiple attributes. Some of the attributes should be fetched using a WFS endpoint. This means, I send the coordinates of the current dataset to the WFS endpoint and get back a certain value (e.g. the zone which the current point is in)…

How can I achieve that whenever I add a new entry to my GeoPackage layer, the value from the WFS is fetched automatically?